# Stop NetworkManager from setting every network as auto-connect?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I know that to stop automatically connect to a network, I have to do :  Click on Wi-fi Icon >> Edit Connections >> Then, Click On Wireless Tab, Delete or Edit the wireless connection.
But I would like the NetworkManager to set every new connection auto-connect property to something like auto-connect=false by default. So every time I connect to a public network, I don't have to remember to delete or edit it.

Comment: Auto-connect is a feature, not a bug. When you connect to a public network, and you're done, walk away. The profile remains. When you return to the same public network, you'll be connected without having to set up a new connection along with password.

Comment: Ok, but does that means that it can not be disabled ?

Comment: Sure. As you've noted, you can go into the wireless profile and uncheck the auto-connect... but why? When you walk away from a wireless network, it'll disconnect, the profile will remain, and if/when you return to the same wireless network area, you'll reconnect automatically. No effort on your part.

Comment: I understand that. But let's say I don't want that behavior.  Can I configure the NetworkManager permanently, to not set auto-connect for new networks ?

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's clever to auto-connect to as-yet-unknown networks without even asking.

Comment: In my case.. it is a laptop, being using as a desktop... Only occasionally do I undock and move around with it!  I don't want NM enabling wifi, unless I really am roaming as the wired port is the normal port.  but Wifi is over riding it!